# 95 Honda civic timing marks

Tags: honda, civic, timing-belt, timing

I have a 95 Honda civic with a D16Z6 engine. I was trying to check the timing on the car, and wanted to get the engine to TDC. There were a few marks on the cam gear. There was no up pointing arrow, so I was unsure on which I should use. The linked picture shows the 3 marks at the top. One is a red dot. The other marks are at the bottom with some ticks and a dial looking thing. It lines up with a little notch at the bottom of the timing belt cover so I was thinking that may be the marker. There were also no little marks on the crankcase nut by the bottom of the car. Any help would be nice! Thanks.

[image: OPs image download]

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like your timing gear is 180 out (upside down) if you are looking for TDC on the compression stroke. If I were a betting man, I'd suggest the writing on the gear itself should be upright to get it correct, with the degree marks (which are at the bottom now) on top so you can see them easily to clock the gear correctly.

Comment: That's what I thought too, which was why when I first changed my head gasket I put it in TDC by making sure the line with the degree marks was straight up. Car doesn't start now, and after diagnosing a bit a friend said timing was off a tooth. After looking for timing marks and such, this seemed like the logical way, but then again I have no clue about this after market cam haha, that does make sense though

Comment: Is the engine doing nothing to fire? Or does it backfire through the intake?

Comment: Engine does nothing, cranked it once and I felt something fire, but it never got started, usually just cranks and does nothing though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotate the engine so the timing hashes on the VMS cam gear are straight up. Ensure piston #1 is at TDC by checking on the timing mark on the crank pulley is lined up with the mark on the timing cover. There are four marks on the timing cover. Use the one to the right (by itself):

[image: Image pulled from CRX Community]

It should look like this when aligned:

[image: Image pulled from CRX Community]

Now go back to your timing gear. First, ensure your hash timing marks are set straight-up (without ***R*** etard or ***A*** dvance). If it shows either side of dead center, adjust it. The timing gear looks as though it has several different marks on it from your picture. The one you should be looking at should be near the 7 O'clock position (on the bottom, just slightly offset to the left). Align this mark with the mark at the bottom left of this picture:

[image]

Ensure the two alignment marks are lined up. You'll probably have to pull the timing belt and get it to the right tooth, which I'm assuming it isn't already.

Give this a shot as it should leave you in good shape.

Comment: This is great, I'll have to look for that tick and line it up! I think a friend already lined that up for me, and the can was off TDC by a tooth. But the line I was using was the one right in the middle of the little ticks, it was right in the middle of the retard and advance marks, so would it be right? It also lined up with the notch too

Comment: Yes ... straight up as I said. Directly between the **R** and the **A**.

Comment: great i did like what said started the car easy

Answer (score 3):

I think the biggest issue that your are potentially having is the aftermarket cam sprocket.

The stock sprocket has an UP mark with to horizontal markers that you align to the valve cover surface.

[image]

Hope this helps, best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a little haha, but the aftermarket cam is the whole problem lol. I know it does have the two Libes on the side to make sure its aligned with the valve cover surface, but I'm unsure about if I should use the red dot and the dashes for TDC, or the little dial at the bottom

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, and it seemed like the dial does line up with the notch at TDC so I might just use that

Comment: There's no marks near the little nut to crank it, but I haven't checked the pulleys real thoroughly, the answer right below here will help a lot I think now that I can see where the marks are.